# For those who hold that David sinned, how was he allowed to ever marry Bat Sheba?

Tags: marriage, king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of, arayot

I might be erring here, but IIRC adulterers can't ever be married.

For those who hold that David did sin, how was he allowed to marry Bat Sheba?

Answer (score 11):

The Gemara in [Kesubos 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.9a.11?lang=bi) asks that question and gives two answers 1) The woman only becomes forbidden (to her husband, and as a consequence also to the adulterer) if she willingly commits adultery. Bas Sheva did not have a choice, so she did not become forbidden. 2) She had a get, so it technically was not adultery.

Comment: Technically, only the first is relevant, because the question assumes adultery. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough. I just quoted the Gemara.

Comment: Does this answer imply that David raped Bat Sheva? That is not apparent in the pesukim

Comment: @rikitikitembo He was a king, so she had no choice.

Comment: @N.T. interesting. So if a king commands a woman to sleep with him against her will it is not rape?

Comment: @rikitikitembo It does not say if she wanted to or not. I'm not aware of a Chazal that says one way or the other. But since she did it by his command, it is not her choice.

Answer (score 4):

This question is raised by Abarbanel in his commentary to Chapter 11:

> השאלה השלישית למה לא צוה האל יתברך לדוד ולא הזהירו הנביא גם כן שיעזוב את בת שבע אחרי שהושרשנו במסכת סוטה שהאשה הנבעלת מתחת בעלה הלא היא אסורה לבעל ואסורה לבועל ואם דוד עשה תשובה איך לא עזב החטא בהיות עזיבת החטא תנאי הכרחי מאד והוא העקר בתשובה ואיך האל יתברך בהיות הענין רע בעיניו בחר שתשאר בת שבע עם דוד ושיהיה שלמה בנה מלך על ישראל והשם אהבו

He repeats the question in his commentary to Chapter 12:

> ואמנם למה לא צוה נתן הנביא את דוד שיעזוב בת שבע אחרי היותה אסורה לו בהיות שזנתה מתחת בעלה בחייו והיתה מפני זה אסורה לבועל

He provides two answers (besides for the argument that it wasn’t really adultery).

1. God wanted to keep the matter secret, so he allowed David to remain with Batsheva, and punished him in private.

   > האחד לפי שהיה זה הענין בסתר וכמו שהוכחתי עד שמפני זה מהר דוד לקחת את בת שבע אחרי מות אוריה מפני היותה כבר
   > הרה ואם היה מתאחר מללוקחה יתפרסם הענין אח”כ כשתלד קודם תשעה חדשים אחרי לקוחיה ולכן רצה ית’ שיהיה הדבר סתום וחתום ואיש אל ידע בכל אלה לכבוד המלכות ולכבוד תורת הש”י ואם היה מצוה הקב”ה שתהיה בת שבע אסורה לדוד תגלה רעתו ויהיה הדבר גלוי לכל עמים וכדי בזיון וקצף לכן העלים עליו הקב”ה מלהעניש בפרסום את דוד די מריו על דבר אוריה ועל ענין בת שבע ורצה שלא ידע אותו בלתו אבל יחשבו הרואים שאוריה מת במלחמה כדרך כל הארץ ושדוד נשא אשתו בהיותה אלמנה בדרך הגון וראוי הלא תראה שאבשלום לא ידע דבר
   > מזה ולכן לא הוציא ממנו דבה על אביו ושמעי בן גרא בקללו את דוד לא זכר מזה כלל להיות הדבר בלתי נודע אצלם עם היות שחז”ל רמזוהו בדבריו אבל הוא על צד הדרש ואדוני’ בן חגית בהתנשאו למלוך לא אמר שהיה שלמה בן זנונים ושאינו ראוי למלוך לפי שלא ידע מזה דבר הנה אם כן הערים הקב”ה להסתיר הדבר ולכן לא צוה שיעזוב דוד את בת שבע אבל הענישו עליו כראוי באופן נסתר הסבה מבני אדם בימים ההם ואחרי קבלת ענשו לא נשאר עליו חטא משפט מות ועל זה אמר דוד מזמור
   > אשרי נשוי פשע כסוי חטאה ואמר שם אתה סתר לי וגו׳ אמנם אחרי כן צוה האל ית׳ לנביא שיכתוב בספר את חטאו כדי שילמדו בעלי חטאות לשוב אל ה׳ בכל לבם ובכל נפשם כאשר עשה דוד ויבטחו בו ית׳ שיכפר בעד חטאתם כאשר כפר לדוד וכמ”ש אלמדה פושעים דרכיך וגו
2. David and Batsheva was a particularly fitting union, and was meant to occur even if David had not sinned.

   > והסבה השנית היא שהאל ית’ ראה בחכמתו העליונה שהיתה עתידה בת שבע שיצא ממנה מושל בישראל ומלך עליון על כל הארץ ושיחכם מכל בני קדם ולכן אותה הוכיח לדוד להוליד ממנה איש יורש את כסאו ואין עלינו להפליא איכה ואיככה ולמה לא יבחר בשאר נשי דוד כמו שלא ידענו למה לא בחר ה’ בכל בני ישי ובחר בדוד עבדו ויקחהו ממכלאות צאן כי ממנו כל דבר והוא ידע מי האיש הירא ומזגו וטבעו ותכונתו ראוי למלוך ומי האשה היותר מוכנת בטבעה מזגה ותכונתה להוליד בן חכם ישמח אב עליון למלכי ארץ הראית מה שאמרו חז”ל
   > במס’ סנהדרין פרק חלק ראויה היתה בת שבע לדוד אלא שאכלה פגה ויורה שהיה דעתם שעתיד היה אוריה לנפול במלחמה או למות מיתה טבעית או כרתיית ותנשא בת שבע לדוד להוליד ממנה משיח אלהי יעקב ושדוד חטא במה שעשה ביצרו הרע והקדים לעשות בחטא מה שהיה עתיד הקב”ה לתת לו בהיתר וזהו אמרם אכלה פגה הנה בעבור זה ראתה החכמה העליונה להעניש דוד על מה שעשה ולהקים אמרתו לתת לו בת שבע לאשה להוליד ממנה שלמה בחיר ה’ ומפני זה זכר הכתוב שמת הילד הראשון אשר ילדה בת שבע לפי שבא קודם זמנו והיה כדמות נובלתושבא דוד אל אשתו כי קראה אשתו אחרי זה כדי להודיע שלא נמנעה ממנו ולכן שכב עמה ויולד את שלמה ושלמה אשר ילדה בזמן הראוי מיד כשנולד אמר הכתוב והשם אהבו והנה לא עשה עדין מעשה שיהיה ראוי להיותו נאהב ממנו יתברך כי אם להיותו נגזר בחכמתו העליונה שיהיה מולך על כל ישראל ויחכם מכל האדם ויהיה יועץ וחכם חרשים ונבון לחש

Comment: Thank you. You stay true to your tradition of quoting the sources without reflecting on them. What do you think it means "*he allowed David to remain with Batsheva*"? Why isn't it mentioned? Do you think he was familiar with Rashi "מפני מה לא אסרוה - על דוד שהרי עדים הרבה ידעו:"?

Comment: @AlBerko When I was writing the answer I was considering adding a disclaimer “I know you will not like this answer” :) But he does at least try to provide evidence that no one knew.